# Building hadoop using maven

Tags: hadoop, maven-3

I tried to build hadoop mapreduce project with maven, but it always stuck in following error,
I already perform predefined installation for yarn i.e. Protobuf installation.

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-  plugin:2.3.2:compile (default-compile) on project hadoop-yarn-common: Compilation failure:  Compilation failure:

[ERROR] /home/mohyt/workspace/hadoop-trunk/hadoop-mapreduce-project/hadoop-yarn/hadoop-    yarn-common/src/main/java/org/apache/hadoop/yarn/ipc/ProtoOverHadoopRpcEngine.java:[76,2] method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
[ERROR] /home/mohyt/workspace/hadoop-trunk/hadoop-mapreduce-project/hadoop-yarn/hadoop-yarn-common/src/main/java/org/apache/hadoop/yarn/ipc/ProtoOverHadoopRpcEngine.java:[262,16] org.apache.hadoop.yarn.ipc.ProtoOverHadoopRpcEngine.Server is not abstract and does not override abstract method call(java.lang.String,org.apache.hadoop.io.Writable,long) in org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server
[ERROR] /home/mohyt/workspace/hadoop-trunk/hadoop-mapreduce-project/hadoop-yarn/hadoop-yarn-common/src/main/java/org/apache/hadoop/yarn/ipc/ProtoOverHadoopRpcEngine.java:[319,4] method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.2:compile (default-compile) on project hadoop-yarn-common: Compilation failure
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:213)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:84)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:59)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.singleThreadedBuild(LifecycleStarter.java:183)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:161)
at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:319)
at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:156)
at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:534)
at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:196)
at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:141)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:290)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:230)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:409)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:352)
    Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.CompilationFailureException: Compilation failure
at org.apache.maven.plugin.AbstractCompilerMojo.execute(AbstractCompilerMojo.java:656)
at org.apache.maven.plugin.CompilerMojo.execute(CompilerMojo.java:128)
at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:107)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:209)
... 19 more
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
[ ERROR] 
[ERROR] After correcting the problems, you can resume the build with the command
[ERROR]   mvn <goals> -rf :hadoop-yarn-common
```

Answer (score 1):

I came across same problem during hadoop 2.2.0 source code building. During "mvn install -DskipTests" this error came in "Hadoop Auth" Folder.
From somewhere(i dont remember from where) i came to know that there is one missing dependency in pom.xml of this Hadoop Auth  folder

dependency is

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
  <artifactId>jetty-util</artifactId>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

I added this dependency and again tried "mvn install -DskipTests". My error resolved.
Hope this will work in your case also

Answer (score 0):

Apache [documentation](http://hadoop.apache.org/common/docs/r0.21.0/single_node_setup.html#Required+Software) says 'JavaTM 1.6.x, preferably from Sun, must be installed.'.

Also, check the [override](http://javamoods.blogspot.com/2010/02/override-changes-in-java-6.html) behavior in the different versions of Java.

Looks like you have Java 5.